# Still getting ORA-04068 (existing state of packages has been discarded) after second try WHEN I use exception handler

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

I have the following test setup:

```
create or replace PACKAGE pkg_state
AS
   FUNCTION get_variable RETURN VARCHAR2;
END pkg_state;
/

create or replace PACKAGE BODY pkg_state
AS
   g_pkg_variable NUMBER(10) := 2; --testa

   FUNCTION get_variable
   RETURN VARCHAR2
   AS
   BEGIN
      RETURN 'FALSE ';
   END get_variable;

END pkg_state;
/
```

Here the test call:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
 v_ReturnValue  VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
  v_ReturnValue := PKG_STATE.get_variable();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_ReturnValue = ' || v_ReturnValue);
 exception when others then 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR');
    --raise;
END;
```

If I run this and change the package in another session I will get the error ORA-04068 -> Expected.

But if I run it again (without changing the package again) it will fail again (and every try after that)!

If I reraise the error (remove comments of the "raise;") everything works as expected: First time error; Second time it works.

I thought it will always work on the second try. Why doesnt it when I'm "swallowing" the error? Never read sth about this specific issue.

This seems to make it impossible to catch the Error and try to make the call again without the user noticing any Errors.
(DB 11.2.0.4)

Comment: Why catch the error? This will never happen in a production environment , except when you are updating the software?

Comment: I get this a lot during development but never had a problem with it in production.

Comment: It happens rarely in production when we need hotfixes where we cant call a downtime. 1.) In theory it would be good to catch that ORA, try run your logic again and just raise it when it fails a second time. But this doesnt seem to work as my example shows. 2.) We have huge amounts of old and bad code which have "when others" without reraising the error.

Comment: Maybe this has some useful hints: 
https://markhoxey.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/avoiding-ora-04068-existing-state-of-packages-has-been-discarded/

Comment: Thx Rene. Most of the information I already know, but I am interessted in the "Trap and Retry" part of that blogpost. This can never work if you need to reraise the error in order to have the second call work.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle keeps a compiled instance of the packages in the session memory of each session. If the package gets invalid it is reloaded.

Therefore propagating this error (raise) is required to clean up the invalid packages.

Trying to ignore the invalid state of package variables is bad practice.

Comment: "Ignoring" is too harsh. Maybe I know exactly what state is now broken so I could catch that exception and redirect the user to the last step where I know everything is valid without having the user see an Error.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with such issue, just re-run the code again from exception block:

```
DECLARE
 v_ReturnValue  VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
  v_ReturnValue := PKG_STATE.get_variable();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_ReturnValue = ' || v_ReturnValue);
 exception when others then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR');
     v_ReturnValue := PKG_STATE.get_variable();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_ReturnValue = ' || v_ReturnValue);
END;
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesnt work.That's my problem: If you dont reraise in the exception block it wont work...